# When I click on "proceed to checkout" button getting error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, custom

When I click on "proceed to checkout" button getting error time to implement custom payment method.

config.xml

[image]
[image]

> app\code\local\Excellence\Pay\Model\Pay.php

```
class Excellence_Pay_Model_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

    protected $_code = 'pay';
    protected $_formBlockType = 'pay/form_pay';
    protected $_infoBlockType = 'pay/info_pay';
    public function assignData($data)
    {
        if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
            $data = new Varien_Object($data);
        }
        $info = $this->getInfoInstance();
        $info->setCheckNo($data->getCheckNo())
        ->setCheckDate($data->getCheckDate());
        return $this;
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        parent::validate();

        $info = $this->getInfoInstance();

        $no = $info->getCheckNo();
        $date = $info->getCheckDate();
        if(empty($no) || empty($date)){
            $errorCode = 'invalid_data';
            $errorMsg = $this->_getHelper()->__('Check No and Date are required fields');
        }

        if($errorMsg){
            Mage::throwException($errorMsg);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The Error is:-

[image]

Comment: Could you post your plugin's XML files? I think you are extending something wrong, or overwriting something wrong.

Comment: I add the config.xml @AngelsDustz

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the issue is in the `config.xml` like I suspected.

More specifically you call for a model called `pay/pay` which doesn't exist for it is searching in `Mage/{first_key}/Model/{secondary_key}`.

I took a quick look but I couldn't find which model you have to extend, but the issue is at `default -> payment -> pay -> model`